# Writing a new column in pandas based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I am trying to assign one column value based on values of two other columns containing string values. I have tried the following, which does not generate any output and just leaved the columns to be filled empty.
Does anyone have a better solution?

```
for i in Table.index:
if pd.notnull(Table['Column1'][i]) and pd.notnull(Table['Column2'][i]):
Table.loc[Table['Column3'][i]] = Table['Column2'][i]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) with `&` for bitwise `AND` and set values in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m = Table['Column1'].notna() & Table['Column2'].notna()
Table.loc[m, 'Column3'] = Table.loc[m, 'Column2']
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try via boolean masking and loc accessor:

```
mask=Table['Column1'].notna() & Table['Column2'].notna()
Table.loc[mask,'Column3']=Table.loc[mask,'Column2']
```

Comment: Thanks, this however raises an error (KeyError: 'Column1'). When I print this column as a standalone command it does not raise any error.. Would it still be necessary to integrate it in the for loop with index i?

Comment: @progammerattempt well sir this answer is according to the code you provided(bcz you used 'Column1' in your code)....pls check if 'Column1' is present in the output of `Table.columns`

Comment: Yeah it is clearly present, so not sure what causes it at this point..

Comment: @progammerattempt sir kindly check again as there may be a whitespace `' '` at either side of it

Comment: ..it doesn't since the column can be printed   and shows up in the columns command..mmmh

Comment: @progammerattempt sir can you pls post the output of `Table.columns`?

Comment: The data is confidential. I have tested 'table.columns' which listed the column also in the same typing as in my code... So I don't believe absence or diverging namings of the column is the problem..

Comment: @progammerattempt Well that's what keyerror means